# Different Blocking retry for Main and non blocking topic

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to implement blocking and non blocking retries by following
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic-combine-blocking

When I use BlockingRetriesConfigurer it is applied to both the Main Topic as well as the Non Blocking Topic . Is it possible to have different blocking retry mechanism for both .

This is my use case
Main Topic Name : "MainEvent"
Non Blocking Topic Name: "RetryEvent"

I want to first implement Blocking Retry on the "MainEvent" topic .Messages not processed in the "MainEvent" topic after the retries should move to "RetryEvent" topic .I want to have a different blocking retry implementation for topic "RetryEvent".

I have followed https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic-combine-blocking with spring-kafka version 2.9.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same configuration is applied to all containers.

However, you should be able to implement custom retry behavior by adding a backoff function to the error handler.

```java
/**
 * Set a function to dynamically determine the {@link BackOff} to use, based on the
 * consumer record and/or exception. If null is returned, the default BackOff will be
 * used.
 * @param backOffFunction the function.
 * @since 2.6
 */
public void setBackOffFunction(BiFunction<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception, BackOff> backOffFunction) {
```

You can decide based on the source topic in the record and the exception type. For a blocking retry, return a `BackOff` that supports retries; for a non-blocking retry, return a `FixedBackOff(0L, 0L)`.

Use the `configureCustomizers()` method to set the function on the error handler.